# Is there any way to customize the template of tile?

Tags: uwp, live-tile

Now I implement live tile on my UWP application.

I found some tile template on MSDN(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#versions) but **i want to change the style of template such as text size.**
In my investigation, I didn't find any way to change the template of tile.
Is there any way to change that? Or is there any way to use custom template?

```
string tileXmlString = "<tile>"
                             + "<visual>"
                             + "<binding template='TileWide310x150SmallImageAndText04'>"
                             + "<image id='1' src='ms-appx:///images/tile-sdk.png'/>"
                             + "<text id='1'>TEXT ID 1</text>"
                             + "<text id='2'>TEXT ID 2</text>"
                             + "</binding>"
                             + "</visual>"
                             + "</tile>";
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a legacy tile template. What you're looking for in UWP are [adaptive tile templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt590880.aspx), which are entirely customizable, and don't rely on fixed templates like the legacy ones (which come from Windows 8/8.1).

In adaptive tile templates, you use the `hint-style` attribute to customize your text elements rather than IDs that map to fixed text blocks. Here's the first example that's given by the link above:

```xml
<tile>
  <visual>

    <binding template="TileMedium">
      ...
    </binding>

    <binding template="TileWide">
      <text hint-style="subtitle">Jennifer Parker</text>
      <text hint-style="captionSubtle">Photos from our trip</text>
      <text hint-style="captionSubtle">Check out these awesome photos I took while in New Zealand!</text>
    </binding>

    <binding template="TileLarge">
      ...
    </binding>

  </visual>
</tile>
```

**Result:**

[image]